# Como puedo hacer para que un elemento boton que esta dentro de un gridview ocupe el tamaño completo de la columna en xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, gridview, xamarinforms

hola colegas estoy realizando un proyecto en visual studio 2019 usando lenguaje C# , el proyecto es para Android, y tengo la siguiente disyuntiva tengo un listview en el que muestro unos datos, el mismo contiene para organizar los mismos un gridview con dos columnas, lo cierto es que quiero alinear los valores hacia la izquierda, pero cuando le pongo al componente la propiedad de     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" el se me alinea a la izquierda pero sin embargo no ocupa el ancho completo de la columna, si le retiro esa propiedad entonces se me alinea por defecto al medio y si coge el ancho de la columna, aqui les envio mi codigo en xaml y una imagen de como esta ahora con la propiedad horizontal option en startandspand [image: ejemplo de como se ve la apk]
mi codigo xaml es el siguiente

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       BorderColor="Black"                                                               
                       CornerRadius="5" 
                       x:Name="frmresultados"
                       BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"  >                                                 
                              
                    <control:AutoScrollListView x:Name="lstpedidos" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Pedidos}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                      SeparatorColor="#1c1c1c"
                                      >
                            
                            <control:AutoScrollListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="50,*"
                                          ColumnSpacing="1" 
                                          >

                                            <Button        x:Name="lblcantidad"
                                                           Text="{Binding CantidadArt}"
                                                           TextColor="White"
                                                           BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                                           FontSize="15" 
                                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Margin="0,3,3,0"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"                                                           
                                                           Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CambiarUnidadCommand,Source={x:Reference lstpedidos}}" 
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                       
                                                            >
                                                
                                                     
                                            </Button>


                                            <Button        x:Name="lbldescripcion"
                                                           Text="{Binding DescripcionArt}"
                                                           TextColor="White"
                                                           FontSize="15"
                                                           BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Margin="0,3,3,0"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                           >
                                            </Button>



                                        </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </control:AutoScrollListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </control:AutoScrollListView>
                </Frame>
```

si algun colega me pudiera orientar se lo agradeceria soy nuevo en estos menesteres y quisiera aprender mas, saludos y pasen buen dia.